# Change parent class depend on variable

Tags: php, oop

How can i set parent class depend on some statement?

Example

```
$switcher = true;

if($switcher) {
 class a extends class1{
 ...
}
else {
 class a extends class2 {
 ...
}
```

i need something like this

```
$myclass = $switcher ? 'class1' : 'class2';

class a extends $myclass { //sure this will not work
```

But how to use `$myclass` without `eval`

Thanks

Comment: Scaaaaary! Just: Don't do it! :) Depending on what you _really_ want to achieve there are plenty of _real_ solutions. The most simple is a very common dependency :) `class A { public function __construct (Behaviour $b) { /* your code */ }} $a = new A(new Behaviour1);`

Answer (score 5):

Classes are parsed at compile time, not runtime, so in effect you *cannot*. Consider instead creating 2 classes with different parents and instantiating them dynamically according to your `$switcher`. It doesn't make much sense to try to change an inheritance hierarchy at runtime.

Your intended approach seems to be crying out for rethinking the architecture.  If `class1` and `class2` are distinct classes, then they by definition should not have much in common to be interchangeable to downstream child classes, and if they *do* have a lot in common, it may point to a problem higher in the inheritance heirarchy, where one might perhaps need to inherit from the other.

Answer (score 1):

The common sense approach would be the one of declaring two classes, let's call them `A1` and `A2`, one extending `Class1`, the other extending `Class2`. Then, you decide which one you want to instantiate.

However you can't do exactly what you want it without `eval`. PHP supports anonymous functions and closures, but doesn't support anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
class MyCommon {}
class MyClassA extends MyCommon {}
class MyClassB extends MyCommon {}

$switcher = true;

if ($switcher) {
    $myinstance = new MyClassA();
} else {
    $myinstance = new MyClassB();
}

var_dump($myinstance instanceof MyCommon); // true, because of inheritance
var_dump($myinstance instanceof MyClassA); // true
var_dump($myinstance instanceof MyClassB); // false
var_dump(get_class($myinstance)); // "MyClassA"
```